# scroll recyclerview after click item of another recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll recyclerview by click on category position of another recyclerview which is called in popup menu...Below is my code, I am using Sectional Recyclerview and i want to get section item position while click on second recyclerview item...Please note that both recyclerview item's category id is same;

CategoryMenuRecyclerview Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<MenuItem.ProductCategory> mDataset;
    private ItemListner itemListner;
    RestaurantMenuActivity mContext;

    public MyAdapter(RestaurantMenuActivity mContext, ArrayList<MenuItem.ProductCategory> productList, ItemListner itemListner) {
        mDataset = productList;
        this.itemListner = itemListner;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public View mainView;
        TextView tvCategory, tvCategoryNo;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mainView = v;
            tvCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            tvCategoryNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryNo);
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_category, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.tvCategory.setText(mDataset.get(position).getCategoryName());

        holder.mainView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                itemListner.Item(position);

            }
        });
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

and i want to scroll below adapter with click item of upper recyclerview item;

RestaurantMenuAdapter;

```
     public class RestaurantMenuAdapter extends SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<MenuItem.ProductCategory> allData;

    public RestaurantMenuAdapter(List<MenuItem.ProductCategory> data) {
        this.allData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionCount() {
        return allData == null ? 0 : allData.size();
    }

    private MenuItem.ProductCategory getItem(int position) {
        return allData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(int section) {
        return allData.get(section).getProductDetails() == null ? 0 : allData.get(section).getProductDetails().size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int section) {
        String sectionName = allData.get(section).getCategoryName();
        SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder = (SectionViewHolder) holder;
        sectionViewHolder.tvCategory.setText(sectionName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int section, final int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {
        final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        itemViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getProductName());
        itemViewHolder.tvDescription.setText("Grass Fed Beef with creespy bacon, tasty cheese, salad, relish and hot");
        itemViewHolder.tvPrice.setText("$ " + allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getCurrentPrice());

        if (near_by_restaurant) {
            rlAddCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (tvCategoryCount.getText().toString().matches("0")) {
                rlAddCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                rlAddCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getIsOpen().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                itemViewHolder.ll_product.setAlpha(0.5f);

                itemViewHolder.ll_product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(RestaurantMenuActivity.this)
                                .setMessage("Sorry kitchen is closed")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            } else if (allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getIsSoldout().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                itemViewHolder.tvSoldOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemViewHolder.ll_product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(RestaurantMenuActivity.this)
                                .setMessage("Sorry all items are sold out")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // Your code

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                itemViewHolder.tvSoldOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemViewHolder.ll_product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("cartitems", 0);
                        String strJson = sharedPref.getString("cartdata", "0");

                        try {
                            mainjsonArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Intent i = new Intent(RestaurantMenuActivity.this, ProductCartActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("product_id", allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getProductID());
                        i.putExtra("productCart", true);
                        i.putExtra("product_name", allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getProductName());
                        i.putExtra("product_price", allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getCurrentPrice());
                        try {
                            i.putExtra("jsonArray", mainjsonArray.toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        startActivityForResult(i, PRODUCT_CART);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            rlAddCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            itemViewHolder.ll_product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(RestaurantMenuActivity.this)
                            .setMessage("Sorry you are not in restaurant")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // Your code

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        if (allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getFavorited() == 0) {
            itemViewHolder.ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_02);
        } else {
            itemViewHolder.ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favroite_highlited);
        }

        itemViewHolder.ivFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(RestaurantMenuActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
                JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    YupITApplication.getJsonWithHTTPPost(RestaurantMenuActivity.this, 1, new ServiceCallBack() {
                        @Override
                        public void serviceCallback(int id, JSONObject jsonResult) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            try {
                                if (jsonResult.has("Data") && !jsonResult.getString("Data").equals("")) {
//                                        {"Status":"Success","StatusCode":"200","Message":"Item Favourited!","Data":[]}

                                    if (jsonResult.getString("Message").equalsIgnoreCase("Item Favourited!")) {
                                        itemViewHolder.ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favroite_highlited);
                                    } else {
                                        itemViewHolder.ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_02);
                                    }
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonResult.getString("Message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, Utils.insertfavoriteitem + "&productid=" + allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getProductID() + "&userid=" + customer_id, postdata);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Glide.with(RestaurantMenuActivity.this).load(allData.get(section).getProductDetails().get(relativePosition).getPhotoImagePath())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(itemViewHolder.ivMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, boolean header) {
        View v = null;
        if (header) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, parent, false);

            v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            width = v.getMeasuredWidth();
            height = v.getMeasuredHeight();

            return new SectionViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(v);
        }

    }

    // SectionViewHolder Class for Sections
    public class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView tvCategory;

        public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
        }
    }

    // ItemViewHolder Class for Items in each Section
    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView tvProductName, tvDescription, tvPrice, tvSoldOut;
        LinearLayout ll_product;
        ImageView ivMenu, ivFav;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            tvDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            ivMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMenu);
            ll_product = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_product);
            tvSoldOut = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSoldOut);
            ivFav = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFav);
        }
    }


    public int isSectionHeaderPosition(int position) {
        return Integer.parseInt(allData.get(position).getCategoryID());
    }

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

i think that the position of category in popup menu will be the same as section value of the second recyclerView if you get the position of clicked item in your activity by listening on item's click you can scroll the recyclerView using the LayoutManager.

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter).
```

Comment: How can I get a view by position and pass as a parameter in this code..I am getting correct id

Comment: you can pass the position as a parameter in    scrollToPosition(position) function

Comment: It's every time scroll to bottom ...can't scroll to specific category section